Low pixel intensities from 16-bit unsigned tif files in R
I have two tif images taken on the same instrument, one in rapid mode, and the other in normal mode.  I want to get average pixel intensities using R.  The regular mode image is a 32-bit float, while the fast mode is 16-bit unsigned.  when I use
regular <- readTIFF("reg_image.tif")
max(regular)

fast<- readTIFF("fast_image.tif")
max(fast)

my max for regular is 850, while the max for fast is  0.01275654. If I open them in the windows viewer, these ranges appear accurate.  However, if I open them both in image J, they have similar pixel intensity ranges.
Is there a way to read the fast image into R so that it performs whatever adjustment image J does?
links to files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IZE1H499Ci3RDug38wcVZm_W4O2KPOkt/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXkQ-vE2cgHENKoMDxn5XCWV0VEO8yaS/view?usp=drive_link

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What values are you seeing in image J?

It probably isn't a coincidence that 65536*0.01275654 ~ 836. something has gone wrong with the normalisation of "fast" when it was read by Windows/R. Max value appears to be as floating point fraction of 65536. Try multiplying "fast" by 65536 and then compare histograms.

Consider sharing your images (Dropbox/Google Drive) for a proper answer.

I have edited the original question to include links to the files.

Multiplying fast by 65535 seems to make it match the regular image.
